# How to fabricate a many-to-many model with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm starting with rspec so I don't know how to proceed the following:

I have a many-to-many table between `User` and `Label` called `Assignment`.
E.g.

- "User A" is assigned to "IT"
- "User B" is assigned to "Research"

**Fabricators:**

```
Fabricator(:label) do
  name { sequence(:name) { |i| "Label #{i}" } }
end

Fabricator(:user) do
  email { sequence(:email) { |i| "user#{i}@email.com" } }
  password 'password'
end
```

**Models:**

```
class Label < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :labels, :through => :assignments

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :label   
end

class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :label

  after_create :print_first_user_label_email

  def print_first_user_label_email
    puts self.label.users.first.email
  end

end
```

The Issue have to prints users assigned for the issue's label every time I create an issue. But it requires that a label should already has a link with a user (assignment).

So, a simple Fabricate(:issue) will trigger:

```
let(:issue) { Fabricate(:issue) }

-- Output ---------------------------------------

Failure/Error: let(:issue) { Fabricate(:issue) }
    NoMethodError:
       undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

So, how do I solve that. Stubbing? Seeding in some way the table? Defining in the fabricators?

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 1):

apparence...　its unsatisfactory. how do you make issue.label?

tentatively...
[issue_fabricator]

```
Fabricator(:issue) do
end
```

[spec]

```
let(:label){ Fabricate(:label) }
let(:issue){ Fabricate(:issue, :label=>label) }
#=> undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

okey. and print_first_user_label_email work is...
self    #=> issue
.label  #=> label
.users  #=> [] (empty)
.first  #=> nil
.email  #=> undefined method

Just try it:

```
let(:user) { Fabricate(:user)  }
let(:label){ Fabricate(:label, :users=>[user]) }
let(:issue){ Fabricate(:issue, :label=>label)  }
```

or assign the relations in before{} block.